# How to increment rank when same total marks is there using mysql query?

Tags: sql, mariadb

This is my query:

```
SELECT
    `users`.`id` AS userID,
    `user_tests`.`id`,
    `users`.`profilePic`,
    `users`.`firstName`,
    `user_tests`.`userId`,
    `user_tests`.`isFirstAttempt`,
    `user_tests`.`total_marks`,
    FIND_IN_SET(
        `user_tests`.`total_marks`,
        (
        SELECT
            GROUP_CONCAT(
                DISTINCT `user_tests`.`total_marks`
            ORDER BY
                CAST(
                    `user_tests`.`total_marks` AS DECIMAL(5, 3)
                )
            DESC
            )
        FROM
            `user_tests`
        WHERE
            `user_tests`.`testSeriesId` = '856' AND `user_tests`.`isFirstAttempt` = '1'
    )
    ) AS rank,
FROM
    `user_tests`
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `users`.id = `user_tests`.`userId`
WHERE
    `user_tests`.`isFirstAttempt` = '1' AND `user_tests`.`testSeriesId` = '856'
ORDER BY
    CAST(
        `user_tests`.`total_marks` AS DECIMAL(5, 3)
    )
DESC
    ,
    `submissionTimeInMinutes` ASC,
    `rank` ASC;
```

Output:

[this is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbavM.png)

Expected:

[Here is the expected output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFweR.png)

I am using MariaDB 5.5.68
I've tried using variables to increment but it's showing me the current row number instead of 1,2,3,4,5... numbers.

Can anybody help here?
Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ROW\_NUMBER() in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql)

Comment: No, as I said I am using MariaDB 5.5.68, so it does not support rank() or row_number().

Comment: ROW_NUMBER is also supported by MariaDB 10.2+. So you will have bad luck.  https://mariadb.com/docs/reference/mdb/functions/ROW_NUMBER/

Comment: You would need to indicate how you want to break ties.

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to need a left join as none of the user names are missing. A simple subquery will give you the the ranking by `total_mark` but I'm not sure whether you're counting users or something else. A CTE would let you avoid duplicating some of the logic and might possibly even be faster. I don't know if you have that option.

```
SELECT
    u.id AS userID, t.id, u.profilePic, u.firstName,
    t.userId, t.isFirstAttempt, t.total_marks,
    (
        SELECT count(distinct userId) from FROM user_tests t2
        WHERE     t.isFirstAttempt = 1 AND t.testSeriesId = 856
              AND t.total_marks < t2.total_marks
    ) as num_tests
FROM user_tests t inner join users u ON u.id = t.userId
WHERE t.isFirstAttempt = 1 AND t.testSeriesId = 856
ORDER BY total_marks desc, submissionTimeInMinutes, num_tests desc
```

Comment: This query keeps loading and does not generate any output. Not sure, something is wrong with this query

Comment: Try again without the string conversions and see what that does.